# How to copy a function itself in C?

Tags: c, function, pointers, static, void

I want to copy a function so that the static variables are independent

I tried following, but the problem is that I am just saving the "adress" of the function

```
#include <stdio.h>

void Function() {
    static int counter = 0;
    counter++;
    printf("Counter = %d\n", counter);
}

int main() {
    void (*f1)() = Function;
    void (*f2)() = Function;

    f1();  // Should output 1
    f2();  // Should output 1 (but the output is 2...)

    return 0;
}
```

Is that somehow possible in C?

Comment: It's not possible to copy a function. What is your actual, original and underlying problem you need to solve? Why do you think copying a function is the proper (or only) solution to that problem? Are you really using threads and want each thread to have its own copy of the variable? Then define it with [`thread_local`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/thread/thread_local) [storage](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/storage_duration) instead?

Comment: If it's not related to threads, pass an argument for the counter instead of keeping it as a `static` local variable? Perhaps wrap it in a structure?

Comment: It is not possible to 'make static variables independent'. If you think you need that kind of thing you're using the wrong language. More likely this is an XY problem.

Comment: A workaround for what you're trying to achieve is to create "context" argument to the function and pass the two together.

Comment: Well... it _is_ possible to copy an actual function on the machine level, but it is hardly the right solution here. As for static variables, they aren't actually stored together with the function. Check out this post I once wrote: [What does the static keyword do in C?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/285050) Also, newer versions of the C language has a specifier `_Thread_local` which works kind of like static but you get one unique variable per thread callback function - but that only applies to multi-threaded programs.

Comment: If you want an array of counters so you can do different counting, pass an argument to `Function` to identify which counter to increment and print.  Note that you can't reset the counters to zero when the data is stored inside the function.  You may need to modularize the code so that you can reset specific counters, etc.

Comment: you don't want to copy the function. you want to have multiple instances of some bunch of state. this looks like you want classes in C. what you describe is two instances of a class. without language support, the simplest way I know is to create structs for each instance's state, then pass them to your "methods" so they can operate on your "objects". that's basically the "context" spoken of above.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No.
Long answer:
A function is just some code in memory with a specific address pointing to it. You seem to know that already because of your:

```c
void (*f1)() = Function;
```

where you assign the address of `Function` to `f1`.

So basically when you call

```c
void (*f1)() = Function;
void (*f2)() = Function;
```

you assign the **same** function pointer, thus the same memory address, to `f1` and `f2`. This address was automatically created for `void Function() {...}` and will always be the same within the same execution.

If you want to have the same function twice, you either need to write it twice, or write it as a macro and then create it twice like this:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define function_creator(number) void Function_##number() { \
        static int counter = 0; \
        counter++; \
        printf("Counter = %d\n", counter); \
    }

function_creator(1)
function_creator(2)

int main() {
    void (* f1)() = Function_1;
    void (* f2)() = Function_2;

    f1();  // Should output 1
    f2();  // Should output 1 (and does)

    return 0;
}
```

But I would generally not recommend such macros because they are really difficult to debug. Have fun :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to copy the *function* though. You want to have multiple instances of some bunch of *state*.

This looks like you want classes in C. What you describe is two instances of a class.

Without language support, the simplest way I know is to create a struct for each instance's state, then pass that to your "method" so it can operate on your "object". That's basically the "context" spoken of in the comments.

Now you just need to decide if you want to be bothered with malloc() and free(), or whether you're content with static allocations.

```c
// you can imagine the includes

typedef struct
{
    int counter;
} state_t;

struct state_t *create_instance()
{
    state_t *instance = malloc(sizeof state_t);
    assert(instance != NULL); // do we use nullptr yet?
    *instance = { .counter = 0 };
    return instance;
}

// destructor is just free(inst)

void increment(state_t *inst)
{
    inst->counter++;
    printf("Counter = %d (instance %p)\n", inst->counter, inst);
}

int main(void)
{
    state_t *inst1, *inst2;
    inst1 = create_instance();
    inst2 = create_instance();

    increment(inst1);  // Should output 1
    increment(inst2);  // Should output 1 as well

    free(inst1); free(inst2);
    return 0;
}
```

I know of no way to "create a function" (closure?) around this so that you can simply pass a function pointer taking no arguments at all.